# PHP, array count, two foreach combination

Tags: php, foreach, count

I am solving this not understandable script, I even don't know where from to start. Maybe someone will help me.
I got two arrays example:

```
$a1 = array(1,2,3 ...);
$a2 = array(4,5,6 ...);
```

what I need is that first array will divide all values by itsel
for this I would like to get script which will work like this (array values can be savet to the same name because will be anyway continue with them, can be new variable, in this example I use new). In the same way variable can be devidet by itself to get 1 but prefer not to. Example of count.

```
$b1 = array([0]/[1], [0]/[2], [0]/[3], [1]/[0], [1]/[2], [1]/[3], [2]/[0], [2]/[1], [2]/[3], [3]/[0], [3]/[1], [3]/[2]);
$b2 = array( *** The same like $b1 ***);
```

On the end will go foreach to write values to table, this I solved already

```
echo "<table><tr>";
    foreach($b1 as $key1 => $val1){
        foreach($b2 as $key2 =>$val2){

           echo "<td>".$key1.$key2."<br/>".val1*val2."</td>";

        }
        echo "</tr><tr>"; 
      }
    echo "</tr></table>"
```

Anyone can give me a help to this issue?

Comment: Why is there a zero in your $b1?

Comment: sorry I solved .. It wasn't so difficult to think little more hard .. in foreach write $val*$val

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do the division of each element is relatively simple. You do it with 2 for loops. The one thing you have to bear in mind, however, is avoiding division by 0. Do you have elements that could be 0? If so, do you want the division result to be 0, or the same as the numerator? the code I show below assumes the latter:

```
function getDivided($array) {
    $length = count($array);
    $return = [];
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        for ($j = 0; $j < $length; $j++) {
            if ($i === $j) continue;
            //the following assumes that the values in the array are never < 1 Change this according to your needs
            $return[] = $array[$i] / max($array[$j], 1);

            //Another option is to use a conditional
            $return[] = $array[$j] === 0 ? $array[$i] : $array[$i] / $array[$j];
        }
    }

    return $return;
}

$b1 = getDivided($a1);
$b2 = getDivided($a2);
```

Comment: thank you very much for your time and help. Appreciate it :)